# how to provide links to the words which are same as in wikipedia

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

As i want to make an application like a wikipedia... I have tried with normal asp.net web application... It is not possible to provide link to the words of any given paragrph...
Its only possible by using wiki like dotnetwiki, screwturn wiki, etc...

Is there any other tools for it..

Comment: @DJKRAZE.. i have given a sample that i want to do like this

Comment: Good luck I can't make heads or tails out of your example or logical reasoning.. good night

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? unable to understand your requirement? what exactly you require?

Comment: That's AutoLink. (not http://... linking) AutoLink is links all page names in wiki site to appropriate pages automatically.
Major feature in a Japanese Wiki engine. (ex.[PukiWiki](http://sourceforge.jp/projects/pukiwiki/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent 5 minutes reading your question and I think the word you are after is: **Wiki links**.

In most wiki's you put double square brackets around words you wish to be links to other pages.

```
[[Programming]]
```

I've researched a few good solutions and I suggest you incorporate/investigate one of these  libraries and put the code into your project.

**Roadkill .NET Wiki engine:**

- Free, open source (Ms-PL)
- Wizard-based installer
- Supports Creole, Markdown and Media Wiki syntax
- Both database and Active Directory security by default
- Very easy to theme: comes with a mediawiki theme by default
- Comes with a screw-turn importer

**DotNetWiki**
DotNetWiki is a simple wiki engine running on Asp.Net and SQL Server. It purpose is to provide a no frills wiki engine that can be deployed easily, is simple to modify and provides some basic authentication capabilities. Features:

- Highly skinnable
- Runs on Asp.Net 2.0
- Uses a SQL Server Database
- Uses Asp.Net Membership Providers for Authentication
- Allows you to lock out pages
- Supports Google Analytic

**Thufir**
It is like Wiki-Wiki but has a what-you-see-is-what-you-get interface.

**FlexWiki**
FlexWiki is an implemention of Wiki, a collaborative text environment.

**DevHawk Wiki**
Wiki implementation for .NET.

**Perspective Wiki Engine**
Perspective is a Wiki engine that includes WYSIWYG editing and multiple security models (including authentication using Windows Domains and Active Directory). Attachments are supported. Searching is supported over common file formats: particular MS Office documents.

**ProntoWiki**
ProntoWiki is a wiki engine/site written in C# with VWD (Visual Web Developer), using ASP.NET 2.0 with SQLExpress 2005 as the backend. The wiki engine is quick and easy to use, and allows text markup equivalent to that of a rich text editor. It accepts image and file attachments automatically through the web interface. Other features include page preview prior to post/update, user authentication based on roles, a customizable appearance and layout using web parts, history tracking, and search functionality.

**Deki Wiki**
Deki Wiki is a free open source wiki and application platform for communities and enterprises. MindTouch DekiWiki was developed with an emphasis on usability, open standards, extensibility, and performance. DekiWiki began as a MediaWiki fork that was beta tested for a year and half across multiple verticals and use scenarios: manufacturing, education, non-profit, interactive design, software design and development, and more. Based on input from the beta users DekiWiki evolved into something significantly more than just another wiki. It facilitates information sharing in a contextually rich environment, which makes knowledge capture and sharing significantly better than traditional Intranet tools, network file servers, CMS, and any other wikis. MindTouch DekiWiki has the most comprehensive feature set, which includes a rich WYSIWYG Editor, page level file attachments which are indexed and searchable, hierarchical information organization, image galleries, information discovery tools (RSS feeds and a web interface), page and file versioning, page diffs, page level permissions, time based guest invitations, browse wiki link dialog, in-place images, and all data is stored in XML. Additionally, all control logic is being ported to MindTouch's Dream Framework, which is a .NET/Mono distributed application manager.

**ScrewTurn Wiki**
ScrewTurn Wiki is a performant and simple Wiki engine, written in C# and based on the ASP.NET 2.0 platform. Main features: - No need for a database - No need to touch IIS or ASP.NET configuration - High performance and scalability on every hardware configuration, thanks to a smart and configurable content caching system - Low bandwidth usage, thanks to the (configurable) usage of custom ViewState Compression and HTTP Compression - Simple deployment, administration and usage - Extremely small footprint - Theming available entirely through CSS files (CSS Media Types are fully supported) - Automatic page backups (performing a rollback is as easy as a mouse click) - Secure user accounting system with Administrators and simple Users (with Email account activation), and a built-in admin account - Useful features such as per-Page authorization, the possibility to make the Wiki completely public (no registration needed to edit pages) or forbid the registration of new users - Protected against dangerous files, scripts and spammers (through Captcha control) - Multilanguage interface (EN, IT, DE, FR, ES) - RSS 2.0 notifications for every page as well as for the whole Wiki

**MindTouch DekiWiki**
MindTouch Deki Wiki is a free open source wiki and application platform for communities and enterprises. Deki Wiki is an easy to use and sophisticated wiki for authoring, aggregating, organizing, and sharing content. Deki Wiki is also a platform for creating collaborative applications, or adding wiki capabilities to existing applications.

Comment: can someone tell me how to use this...I have downloaded dotnetwiki framework... but how to use it... no sample code i got from any of the sites... pls help